Investigative type movie where a kid runs in to a kitchen, disappears and then reappears to run in to the same kitchen
It was an investigative type movie where there was a part in which a kid runs in to a kitchen, disappears then reappears to run in to the same kitchen. Can't remember if is was aliens or paranormal type investigation. This scene was also in the trailer.
I think that there is a kid that is abducted or that there was some sort of paranormal activity in the house and there were investigators called in. While taping/investigating I remember that there was a child that they heard laughing and saw said child run in to a kitchen and disappear then reappear and run in to the kitchen/room again. Can't remember much else, which is why I ask. It always stuck out and want to see if I can watch it.  

Kindly provide some more info

Please [edit] the question with your info as comments may get deleted

Welcome to Movies & TV. Although your question appears to have enough info for an identification question, but still details like country/language, approximate  year of movie release, genre,  watched on TV or theaters, in which year you watched it, characters description would really help others to identify the movie. Good Luck.

Maybe Poltergeist (Original) / Poltergeist (Remake) or one of the Paranormal Activities Movies?

You're looking for the horror film Skinwalker Ranch from 2013.

A scientific research team investigates and documents the supernatural phenomena surrounding the disappearance of a cattle rancher's 10 year old son. Inspired by true events that shocked the paranormal community around the world. 

The boy's ghost runs through the kitchen at the same time every night; the team captures it on tape and you can see his appearance there looping in the trailer at 1:09:



